# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with File Access to Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

Aloah my friends,

i've a problem with my **Amazon Elastic Beanstalk** and **Amazon S3** setup.

From the EB instance i want to load a file with node (`fs.readFileSync`), i tried a ton of configurations - but non of them worked, so you're my last hope.

Here is my `.ebextensions/key.config`:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: S3
          buckets: mybucket
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
files:
  /var/app/dummy.txt:
     authentication: S3Auth
     source: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/dummy.txt
```

And here the **bucket policy** from the S3

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "BeanstalkS3",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "e-123-123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/resources/environments/logs/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "e-123-123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when i query the file with node:

```
fs.readFileSync('/var/app/dummy.txt')
```

The log's in EB says:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/app/dummy.txt'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at /var/app/current/server.js:68:25
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /var/app/current/server.js:52:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
```

Important, the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` role has this policies:

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
- AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess

Comment: I think one of the problems is that the `fs.readFile` is executed by the `nodejs` user which runs in a sub shell, so it has no file access